# NHibernate Filters for self join table

Tags: sql, nhibernate, filter

What are NHibernate filters to have the same result as this SQL query:

```
SELECT A.Id as ItemId, A.column1 as ItemTitle, A.ListId as ItemListId,
B.Id as LookupItemId, B.Value as LookupItemValue, B.ListId as LookupItemListId
FROM MyTable A LEFT JOIN MyTable B ON B.Id = A.LookupId     
WHERE A.ListId = 'EmployeeListGuid'
AND (B.ListId='EmployeerListGuid' OR B.Id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create alias for entity property, that will `LEFT JOIN` our table to self:

```
criteria.CreateAlias("LookupItem", "B", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

Then, we can use this alias in criteria:

```
critera.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ListId", "EmployeeListGuid"));    
critera.Add(
    Restrictions
      .Or(
        Restrictions.Eq("B.ListId", "EmployeerListGuid"), 
        Restrictions.IsNull("B.Id")));
```